# My python code only adds even number of names to into groups, need it to add all names (odd or even) to groups

Tags: python-3.x

Currently my script takes a csv list of names, shuffles and sorts them into groups based on the users preference of either *how many groups* or *how many people per group*. There's a flaw in my code that only sorts out an even number of names per group. For example, if there are 30 people in list and the user wants 5 groups, it sorts 6 per group. Additionally, if there's 33 names in the list and the user wants 5 groups, it still only sorts 6 per group, and leaves out the remaining 3 names.

I am a beginner coder and am looking for some help with editing my code to enumerate through the csv and add all names to a group, even if the total number of names is an odd number (for example; group 1-3 each have 7 names and groups 4 & 5 each have 6 names, to equal all 33 names).

Here's my current code:

```
import csv
import random
import pprint
import sys
#import pandas as pd

with open(input('Enter file name: \n'),'r', encoding = 'Latin-1') as csvfile: # opens csv directory file
    rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
    rdr = list(rdr)



def name_generator(lst): # generator that shuffles list of names
    random.shuffle(lst)
    return lst

shuf_lst = name_generator(rdr) # list of shuffled names

headcount = len(shuf_lst) # how many names in the list (will later be rsvp'd names only)

def group_size_generator():
    final_dict2 = {} #initiated blank dictionary
    gpsz = input('How many people per group? \n')
    gpct = int(headcount) // int(gpsz) # number of people per group
    for x in range(int(gpct)):
        final_dict2['group{0}'.format(str(x+1))] = x + 1
    if len(shuf_lst) != 0:
        for k, v in final_dict2.items():
            workinglist = []
            for y in range(int(gpsz)):
                workinglist.append(shuf_lst[0])
                del shuf_lst[0]
            final_dict2[k] = workinglist
        pprint.pprint(final_dict2)

def group_number_generator():
    final_dict1 = {} # initiated blank dictionary
    gpct = input('How many groups? \n')
    gpsz = int(headcount) // int(gpct) #number of of people per group
    print(gpsz)
    for x in range(int(gpct)): # initializes the dict with group identifiers
        final_dict1['group{0}'.format(str(x + 1))] = x + 1
    if len(shuf_lst) != 0: # condition that appends specified number of names per group to the groups in dict
        for k, v in final_dict1.items():
            workinglist = []
            for y in range(int(gpsz)):
                workinglist.append(shuf_lst[0])
                del shuf_lst[0]
            final_dict1[k] = workinglist
        pprint.pprint(final_dict1)

def user(): #user input
    user_input = input('Choose one: \n A.) How may people per group? \n B.) How many groups? \n')
    for x in user_input:
        if x == 'A' or x == 'a':
            return(group_size_generator())
        if x == 'B' or x == 'b':
            return(group_number_generator())
        else:
            print('Error: Appropriate option not selected. Please try again.')

print(user())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only looked at the group_size_generator function (I assume that the group_number_generator uses similar logic), and your the bug actually comes from the logic itself.

**1. Creation of groups**

```
gpct = int(headcount) // int(gpsz) # number of people per group
for x in range(int(gpct)):
    final_dict2['group{0}'.format(str(x+1))] = x + 1
```

From this block, you have a fixed number of groups, regardless of whether there are 30 or 33 people.

**2. Group-based looping**

```
for k, v in final_dict2.items():
    workinglist = []
    for y in range(int(gpsz)):
        workinglist.append(shuf_lst[0])
        del shuf_lst[0]
```

Furthermore, you loop through the groups (not the total number of people). Therefore, once all the groups are filled up, it exits - leaving you with remnants in `shuf_lst` if there are remainders in the division operation.

The code actually looks great for a beginner (good job!). If you loop on the number of people, instead of the number of groups you should be fine. You do not have to init your dict groups before hand too actually. Dicts can be expanded by simple assignment:

```
final_dict2['6'] = workinglist
```

Hence, while your `shuf_lst` is not empty, create a new key for `final_dict2` and assign workinglist to it.